# Java Stream : Group List using multiple type in class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have different set of data like below and Now I want to group by ClientId+EffDate+Seccode

```
    List<Transaction> list = new  ArrayList<Transaction>();


    for (int i=0; i <= 10 ; i++){
        Transaction txn = new Transaction();

        txn.setClientId(i);
        txn.setEffDate("11/11/201"+i);
        txn.setSecCode("PPD");
        list.add(txn);
    }
    for (int i=5; i <= 10 ; i++){
        Transaction txn = new Transaction();

        txn.setClientId(i);
        txn.setEffDate("11/11/201"+i);
        txn.setSecCode("PPD");
        list.add(txn);
    }
```

I want to get data using below criteria

ClientId+EffDate+Seccode get list of transactions

I am trying to do using below incomplete code

```
 Function<Transaction, List<Object>> keyExtractor = wr ->Arrays.<Object>asList(wr.getClientId(), wr.getEffDate(), wr.getSecCode());

 Map<List<Object>, String> aggData = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyExtractor).....
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what's wrong with your code? looks ok to me (except perhaps the return value which would probably be a `Map<List<Object>, Transaction>`).

Comment: `groupingBy` uses the `equals` method. Since the classes `String`, `Integer` and `Arrays$ArrayList` all have value-based `equals` methods, grouping like this shouldn't require extra work. I think you need to clarify exactly what the problem is, and what the result should be.

Comment: I would not use `List<Object>`.  That’s going to be painful for other developers (and for yourself, should you have to revisit the code in a few months).  Also, using a mutable object like a List for a key is dangerous, because the Map will break in mysterious ways if the List used as a key is changed later.  Instead, create a simple key class with three final fields.  Your keyExtractor function could even be replaced with that key class’s constructor:  `Collectors.groupingBy(TransactionKey::new)`

Comment: You want us to complete the missing part of your code? How? You want the groups to get collected to a `String`, so *you* have to tell us, how that should happen. What’s the intended content of these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using below code.

```
    Test data
    ---------

     List<Transaction> list = new  ArrayList<Transaction>();


    for (int i=0; i <= 10 ; i++){
        Transaction txn = new Transaction();

        txn.setClientId(i);
        txn.setEffDate("11/11/201"+i);
        txn.setSecCode("PPD");
        list.add(txn);
    }
    for (int i=0; i <= 5 ; i++){
        Transaction txn = new Transaction();

        txn.setClientId(i);
        txn.setEffDate("11/11/201"+i);
        txn.setSecCode("PPD");
        list.add(txn);
    }


    solution
    --------
    Map<Key, List<Transaction>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getKey));

    for (Key key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println( "key effect ="+ key.getEffdate() + ", sec code =" +key.getSecCode() + " , client id ="+ key.getClientId());
        for( Transaction txn : map.get(key)){
            System.out.println( txn.getEffDate() + " "+ txn.getSecCode() + " " + txn.getClientId());
        }

    }


     Transaction.java 
     ----------------
     public class Transaction {

private int clientId;

private String secCode;

private String effDate;

public int getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(int clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

public String getSecCode() {
    return secCode;
}

public void setSecCode(String secCode) {
    this.secCode = secCode;
}

public String getEffDate() {
    return effDate;
}

public void setEffDate(String effDate) {
    this.effDate = effDate;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + clientId;
    result = prime * result + ((effDate == null) ? 0 : effDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((secCode == null) ? 0 : secCode.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Transaction other = (Transaction) obj;
    if (clientId != other.clientId)
        return false;
    if (effDate == null) {
        if (other.effDate != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!effDate.equals(other.effDate))
        return false;
    if (secCode == null) {
        if (other.secCode != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!secCode.equals(other.secCode))
        return false;
    return true;
}


public Key getKey() {
    return new Key(clientId, secCode,effDate);
}

class Key {

    public int getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(int clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}


    private int clientId;

    private String secCode;

    private String effdate;


    public Key(int clientId, String secCode,String effdate) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.secCode = secCode;
        this.effdate = effdate;

    }

    public String getSecCode() {
        return secCode;
    }

    public void setSecCode(String secCode) {
        this.secCode = secCode;
    }

    public String getEffdate() {
        return effdate;
    }

    public void setEffdate(String effdate) {
        this.effdate = effdate;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + clientId;
        result = prime * result + ((effdate == null) ? 0 : effdate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((secCode == null) ? 0 : secCode.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Key other = (Key) obj;
        if (clientId != other.clientId)
            return false;
        if (effdate == null) {
            if (other.effdate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!effdate.equals(other.effdate))
            return false;
        if (secCode == null) {
            if (other.secCode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!secCode.equals(other.secCode))
            return false;
        return true;
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you are trying to accomplish one of the following:

1. Group Transactions by a single attribute (e.g., client ID); or
2. Group Transactions by all attributes

(1) To group by a single attribute I suggest using a [classifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) that maps to the key you want (e.g., Transaction::getClientId). For example:

```
Map<Integer, List<Transaction>> byClientId = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getClientId), Collections::unmodifiableMap));

System.out.println(byClientId.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .map(e -> e.getKey().toString() + ": " + e.getValue().stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

(2) To group by all attributes I suggest using the [identify function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) as your [classifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and remembering to override [Object::equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). For example:

```
Map<Transaction, List<Transaction>> byTransaction = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()), Collections::unmodifiableMap));

System.out.println(byTransaction.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparing(Transaction::getClientId)
        .thenComparing(Transaction::getEffDate)
        .thenComparing(Transaction::getSecCode)))
    .map(e -> e.getKey().toString() + ": " + e.getValue().stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```